# Programming languages to be used for creating an IM service?

Tags: android, database

I am not a professional programmer, I am more on the business side and haven't coded for a while really. The thing is that I am planning to develop a new IM service for mobile phones, and wanted to know, in your opinions, which are the best programming languages that I should use in the process (to hire people with those knowledge!).

The client application will be for android and iOS, so there's no doubt that Java and Objective C will be used for them. The actual doubts are, first, what database system do you think it would best fit my needs (it is a chat application, so it will probably just record user registration details, friends and possibly logs, but not anything really heavy, and it must be easy to access via mobile devices?) and, secondly, which programming language should I use to program the server based application, which will basically manage the communication itself.

I have been recommended by a friend JSON, for the DB, as it is commonly used in Android applications, and Ruby on Rails for the server. What do you think about that?

Comment: JSON is an interchange format not a database, although there are JSON-based databases such as MongoDB which may have been what your friend meant.

Comment: Yes, actually I expressed it bad, but that was the point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should use [XMPP](http://www.xmpp.org)/Jabber. It's a protocol built for instant messaging. A server like [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) (written in erlang and open source) will do pretty much everything for you. What you will have to do yourself is to build a client for all the different platforms you want your IM service to work on. For Android you can use something like [asmack](http://metajack.im/2010/02/10/xmpp-library-for-android-developers/). I have used the Javascript library [Strophe](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/) from the same author (I think) and it worked well for me. Asmack should be good too I presume.

JSON is a data interchange format. You can actually embed JSON data inside the XMPP data packet.

Answer (score 1):

Why not hire smart server-side engineers and let them pick the technology they feel is most appropriate?

Comment: +1, how about letting the tech guys do the tech and get busy looking for those tech guys? There's no one-size-fits-all answer to your question and you're probably not aware of or are omitting some relevant details here.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. With my wuestion I pretended to know actually what kind of tech guys to hire... Or at least have a general concept of what to look on them. I don't really need a really concrete and detailed answer, just opinions to form myself a better mental idea :)

Comment: I would say that virtually all of the currently popular application server technologies could handle running an IM service.